# using database to store session data, but session files still created

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

I have just implemented a PHP session handler that implements SessionHandlerInterface, thereby storing session info on db, and additionally I am setting up a persistent login.

It seems to be working fine, subject to further testing. Data is being created on db, but this is NOT keeping the session files from being created on the TMP directory, which is a security risk.

So, my question is how to avoid the creation of those redundant files?

I am not sure how much info I should include in order to give you a good overview, but I will start with the changes made to .htaccess concerning php.ini

```
session.save_path still shows as /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php


php_flag session.auto_start off
php_flag session.use_cookies on
php_flag session.use_only_cookies on
php_flag session.use_trans_sid off

php_flag session.use_strict_mode on

php_value session.cache_limiter nocache

# Cookie settings

#php_value session.cookie_domain ''
#php_value session.cookie_path '/SiteCar'
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 0
php_flag session.cookie_httponly on
php_flag session.cookie_secure off // change for production

php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
php_value session.gc_probability 1
php_value session.gc_divisor 100
```

I am also including my initialization script:

```
use UsedSessions\Sessions\PersistentSessionHandler;

require_once 'UsedSessions/Includes/Psr4AutoloaderClass.php';
require_once 'used_connect.php';

$loader = new Psr4AutoloaderClass();
$loader->register();
$loader->addNamespace('UsedSessions', 'UsedSessions');

$handler = new PersistentSessionHandler($ulink);
session_set_save_handler($handler);
session_start();
$_SESSION['active'] = time();

use UsedSessions\Sessions\Autologin;
```

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()` before registering your session save handler?

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston . session_start() is called AFTER session.save_handler. I have included initialization code on my post.

Comment: @RyanVincent - the issue in question, ie, session files still being created does not seem to be related with the persistent session as such. The problem was there already when I first implemented only the session.set_save_handler portion of the set up. In any case, all data IS stored in db

Comment: @RyanVincent - persistent login or automatic login is when you automatically login users that have checked the 'remember me' checkbox at the initial login. So, the info required to do that is stored in db, as is EVERY info on sessions that would normally be on the session files. Again, as I said, that portion should not have any impact on the undesired creation of the session files.

Comment: @RyanVincent. What is your point? Or are you just repeating what I said, to confirm that the persistent login has nothing to do with the issue at hand?